# Getting multiple scripts to run on one web app Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bottle

I have a web app (app.py) that uses bottle.py framework to read realtime data using zeromq from a python script(stream.py, the app then publishes it on to the web app UI.

How would I deploy this app on heroku? Initially I successfully was able to get the web app itself to run with heroku using foreman start but its useless without the script running.

This is my directory:

```
Demo/
    Procfile
    app.py
    stream.py
    requirements.txt
    requirements/
    venv/
         bin/
         lib/
         include/
    static/
         index.html
         lib/
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: python ./streamserver.py $PORT
worker: python ./collector.py
```

Comment: What's the problem? Did you scale the worker app to 1 by running `heroku ps:scale worker=1`?

Comment: I think the problem is that zeromq doesn't work with heroku sadly.

Comment: And why shouldn't it work?

Comment: Heroku doesn't support it.

Comment: If it isn't supported out of the box you can always customize the buildpack to include the zmq libs. This has clearly been done before: http://www.hward.com/zeromq-on-heroku